# Why does php's date function return wrongly formatted date?

Tags: php, date

I want to get the current date via:

```
date('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', time())
```

but this will return:

> 2018201820182018-MarMar-WedWed 0909:0303:4949

Why?

Comment: Notice any correlation between the format string and the output? Four `Y`s, four years, two `M`s two months, etc.

Comment: Incidentally `time()` is pointless there as the current timestamp is the default value. You can leave that out if you like.

Comment: Please be advised that the answer you accepted previously had wrong syntax for minutes. It should be `i` instead of `m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to put each letter once:

```
echo date('Y-M-D h:i:s', time());
```

*Result*

> 2018-Mar-Wed 02:03:27

You can see all the formats and a description in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Comment: `m` is months. `i` is minutes with leading zero.

Comment: @k0pernikus duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
```

It may seem wrong time if you're in different timezone. In that case you can set required timezone using this function like this before using `date()` function-

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
date('Y-M-D h:i:s', time());
```

See the [manual for `date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can see that the 'Y' character already outputs the year in the 4 digit format. The same goes for the other characters.

Comment: m - won't return the minute, but it'll return the month in number.

Comment: `m` is months. `i` is minutes with leading zero.

Comment: Right. Thanks guys.